# Как вычесть значения в массивах PHP

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста ест 2 массива с одинаковым N_KOD, как вычесть `KOLVO_T - SALES_KOLVO` и на выходе повернуть первый массив но с `[KOLVO_T] => 9`

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [N_KOD] => 764460
            [TOV_NAME_G] => HSB HP0021
            [CENA] => 1040
            [CENAI] => 988
            [CENAV] => 492.03
            [KOLVO_T] => 10
        )

[0] => Array
    (
        [N_KOD] => 764460
        [SALES_KOLVO] => 1
    )
```

Comment: в смысле что у вас есть два массива, в которых по нескольо элементов указанного вида?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас приведены примеры элементов исходным массивов, и их в каждом массиве равное число, совпадающие N_KOD, то как-нибудь так

```
$x = array_column($sales, 'SALES_KOLVO', 'N_KOD');

$result = array_map(function($v) use ($x){
               $v['KOLVO_T'] -= $x[$v['N_KOD']] ?? 0;
                return $v;
            }, $data);
```

либо циклами

```
foraech($data as &$d){
    $d['KOLVO_T'] -= $x[$d['N_KOD']] ?? 0;
}
```